# Use the Google Cloud Compute Engine REST API from Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-compute-engine

I am trying to use the Google Cloud Compute Engine REST API from Firebase Functions.
However I'm stuck with how to start, since I can't figure out how to authenticate from Cloud Functions.

[This](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/how-tos/authorization) is the only resource I have found, but I can't figure out how to get it working on Cloud Functions.

Comment: figured it out. I was really struggling with finding the authentication part. But got it now (see my answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Here's how to send REST API calls from Cloud Functions:

```js
const {auth} = require('google-auth-library');
const client = await auth.getClient({
  scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
});

var url = [REQUEST URL HERE]
var data = {[REQUEST BODY HERE]}

response = await client.request({
  url: url,
  method: 'post',
  data: data
})
```